# Accessing components of a class inside a list

Tags: python, arrays, list

So I have this code that doesn't work:

```
class Airport():
 def _init_ (self):
    self.Code_Icao=""
    self.Latitude=""
    self.Longitude=""
    self.Schengen=False
A=Airport()
A.Code_Icao="LMAO"
A.Latitude="12321412"
A.Longitude="12123123"
B=Airport()
B.Code_Icao="JEJE"
B.Latitude="1231231"
B.Longitude="123123"
v=[]
v.append(A.__dict__)
v.append(B.__dict__)
print v[0].Code_Icao
```

I don't know why it doesn't let me access the code of a component of the list.
I keep getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/marc/PycharmProjects/untitled5/read.py", line 18, in 
>       print v[0].Code_Icao AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'Code_Icao'

Comment: `v[0]` is a `dict`, not an `Airport`.  Try `print v[0]['Code_Icao']` instead

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much man! <3

Comment: I'd think v = [A, B] would be closer to what you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following lines:

```
v=[]
v.append(A.__dict__)
v.append(B.__dict__)
```

You're not appending `A` and `B` to `v`, but rather two [dictionaries with `A` and `B`'s writable attributes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__). Note the difference here:

```
>>> A
<__main__.Airport instance at 0x10c30c758>
>>> A.__dict__
{'Latitude': '12321412', 'Longitude': '12123123', 'Code_Icao': 'LMAO'}
```

`A` is an `Airport` object, whereas `A.__dict__` is a dictionary with `A`'s attributes stored in it.

So, since you're storing dictionaries in `v`, you'll have to use the proper notation to access its values:

```
print v[0]['Code_Icao']
```

That should print the value you're trying to get to.